# Replaced Paddle Switch

Tags: wiring

I replaced an old paddle switch after installing backsplash. With the old switch the wires were just pressed into a grid and was rated at 15a. I thought a single pole light switch would work but unfortunately it didn't. I have 2 sets of 14g wire, one is the feed and the other is the outlet. I wired the new switch black on top leg and white on bottom leg. Outlet works when turned on but kicks breaker when switched off. I looked at the old switch and it had one leg connected and the other leg was the paddle. Does this mean I need a 2 pole switch?

Comment: Trying to visualize.  Got any photos?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring please?

Comment: SOLVED - After looking at the old paddle switch, I realized that one side of it was always connected top to bottom and the other side was either open or closed., The solution was to wire all the white together and just attach the black wire to the poles.

Comment: @joe645  Type this up as an answer and then accept it  since you solved your problem.  This  will enter it into the answer base so it can possibly help future DIY's.